# PHP else/if statements

Tags: php, if-statement

I've written the following PHP statement but everytime i try to combine it into an else/if, it breaks.

Can someone please advise? I'm new to PHP and am getting a tad stuck.

Thanks :)

```
<?php if (is_page( 19 ) ) {?>
<div class="imageSlider"><img src="<?php echo bloginfo('template_directory');?>/Images/mainImages/innerPage-Image.jpg" alt="" /><img src="<?php echo bloginfo('template_directory');?>/Images/mainImages/innerPage-Image2.jpg" alt="" /><img src="<?php echo bloginfo('template_directory');?>/Images/mainImages/innerPage-Image3.jpg" alt="" /></div>
<?php }?>

<?php if (is_page( 23 ) ) {?>
<div class="imageSlider"><img src="<?php echo bloginfo('template_directory');?>/Images/mainImages/innerPage-Image.jpg" alt="" /><img src="<?php echo bloginfo('template_directory');?>/Images/mainImages/innerPage-Image.jpg" alt="" /><img src="<?php echo bloginfo('template_directory');?>/Images/mainImages/innerPage-Image.jpg" alt="" /></div>
}
<?php }?>
```

Comment: What's the code that breaks? How did you try to do it?

Comment: `<?php } else if (is_page( 23 ) ) {?>` does not work for you? (no `?><?php` in between there of course).

Answer (score 3):

Use this syntax :

```
<?php if (condtion):?> 
 // html goes here,
<?php elseif(condtion): ?>
 // html goes here,
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php if (is_page( 19 ) ) {?> 
<div class="imageSlider"><img src="<?php echo bloginfo('template_directory');?>/Images/mainImages/innerPage-Image.jpg" alt="" /><img src="<?php echo bloginfo('template_directory');?>/Images/mainImages/innerPage-Image2.jpg" alt="" /><img src="<?php echo bloginfo('template_directory');?>/Images/mainImages/innerPage-Image3.jpg" alt="" /></div> 
<?php } elseif (is_page( 23 ) ) {?> 
<div class="imageSlider"><img src="<?php echo bloginfo('template_directory');?>/Images/mainImages/innerPage-Image.jpg" alt="" /><img src="<?php echo bloginfo('template_directory');?>/Images/mainImages/innerPage-Image.jpg" alt="" /><img src="<?php echo bloginfo('template_directory');?>/Images/mainImages/innerPage-Image.jpg" alt="" /></div>
<?php }?>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Here is an sample if/else using your code**

```
<?php if (is_page(19)) { ?>
    //Insert html
<? { elseif (is_page(23)) } ?>
   //Insert other html
<? } ?>
```

Comment: Shortcodes (`<?=`) aren't recommended because they limit portability.

Comment: Thank you - it was the missing } that had me stumped! And thanks for the advise re the template_directory call

Comment: Oh - so should i stick with the original template_directory call?

Comment: Guess i learned something today, i always use shortcodes. thanks!