# How to add second 'else' in PHP?

Tags: php

Until the last line my code works fine,

If the first link is broken, page 2 will open,

If page number 2 is broken, then page 3 should open.

```
<?php
    $clientproiptv = file_get_contents('/clientproiptv.txt', true);
    $paliptv = file_get_contents('/paliptv.txt', true);
    $url1 = 'http://web.com/1';
    $url2 = 'http://web.com/2';
    $url3 = 'http://web.com/3';
    if(get_headers($url1)) {
        header('Location:'.$url1);
    } else {
        header('Location:'.$url2);
    } 
    // ** from here i need help **
    else {
        header('Location:'.$url3);
    }
```

Comment: are you looking for `elseif`? http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.elseif.php

Comment: You're probably looking for `if() {} elseif() {} else {}` kind of logic.

Comment: Or `switch` if not `elseif`s.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP else/if statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11331594/php-else-if-statements)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
   if(get_headers($url1))
    {
       header('Location:'.$url1);
    }
    else if(get_headers($url2)){
       header('Location:'.$url2);
    }
    else{
     header('Location:'.$url3);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use [`else if`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.elseif.php) like so:

```
<?php
    $clientproiptv = file_get_contents('/clientproiptv.txt', true);
    $paliptv = file_get_contents('/paliptv.txt', true);
    $url1 = 'http://web.com/1';
    $url2 = 'http://web.com/2';
    $url3 = 'http://web.com/3';
    if(get_headers($url1)){
        header('Location:'.$url1);
    } else if(get_headers($url2) {
        header('Location:'.$url2);
    } else {
        header('Location:'.$url3);
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for `elseif` *(PHP 4, PHP 5, PHP 7)*:

**Example code:**

```
<?php
if ($a > $b) {
    echo "a is bigger than b";
} elseif ($a == $b) {
    echo "a is equal to b";
} else {
    echo "a is smaller than b";
}
?>
```

**Documentation:** http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.elseif.php

**Other solution:**

Next to `elseif` you could use `switch` *(PHP 4, PHP 5, PHP 7)*:

```
<?php
switch ($i) {
    case "apple":
        echo "i is apple";
        break;
    case "bar":
        echo "i is bar";
        break;
    case "cake":
        echo "i is cake";
        break;
}
?>
```

**Documentation:** http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php